# Передача данных из input на другую страницу html

Tags: javascript, html, input, href

Помогите пожалуйста с одним вопросом. Перейти на другую страницу я могу, но использовать данные с первой не получается. Вот код:
HTML(первая страница):

````
```
<input type="number" class="secInput" max="59" min="0" value="0" id="secWork">
<a href="C:\Users\Alex23432\Desktop\Сайты\pomodoro timer2\index.html?secWork" id="hr">Поехали!</a>
```
````

JS(вторая страница):

````
```
let result = new URL(location.href).searchParams.get("secWork");
console.log(result);
```
````

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: " не получается." --- не является полным корректным описанием проблемы

Comment: в текущем виде secWork пустой. чтобы он был не пустой он должен быть как минимум `?secWork=ЧТО-ТО`

Comment: Попробовал:"C:\Users\Alex23432\Desktop\Сайты\pomodoro timer2\index.html?secWork=secWork.value". Но в консоли просто выводиться secWork.value

Comment: ...а что должно выводиться? ........`let str = url + document.getElementById('secWork').value`  и дальше это в href

Answer (score 0):

Скорее перед переходом надо нормально заполнить атрибут ссылки (либо при изменении знчения в инпуте - на выбор)

```js
document.getElementById('hr').addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
    let inputValue = document.getElementById('secWork').value;
    target.href = "C:\Users\Alex23432\Desktop\Сайты\pomodoro timer2\index.html?secWork=" + inputValue; 
});
```

```html
<input type="number" class="secInput" max="59" min="0" value="0" id="secWork">
<a href="C:\Users\Alex23432\Desktop\Сайты\pomodoro timer2\index.html?secWork" id="hr">Поехали!</a>
```

---

P.S. Никогда не используйте прямое обращение к элементу по идентификатору без использования методов `getElementById` и `querySelector`. Это всё устарело и может быть когда-либо выпилено и вообще, сейчас это моветон.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли

Comment: А зачем нужен href по умолчаению, достаточно такой ссылки: `<a id="hr">Поехали!</a>`

Comment: @Опан это было у автора. Просто копипаст. Надеюсь он догадается, что не надо так))